# PHP using preg_match to match items in array with values that can or not contain accent characters

Tags: php, preg-match

The `preg_match` must match any of the words in the `$string` variable (as long as they are at least 3 chars long) with any of words in the `$forbidden` array, but here's the issue:

If the `$string` contains the word **mamíferos** (with an accent char) instead of **mamiferos**, it should also be a match. Same applies if **acompañar** is in the forbidden array list, but the user decides to type **acompanar** instead (without the accent char).

```
$forbidden = array('mamiferos', 'acompañar');

$string = 'los mamíferos corren libres y quieren acompanar a su madre';

if(preg_match('/\b(?:'.implode('|', $forbidden).'){3,}/i', $string)) {
    echo 'match!';
} else {
    echo 'nope...';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest a solution based on removing any combining Unicode characters from both the filtered string and the forbidden words. It will require `intl` extension (`sudo apt install php7.4-intl && sudo phpenmod intl`). Firstly, it decomposes the Uncode string into characters and combining letter modifiers, secondly, it removes all modifiers (`\p{M}`):

```php
<?php
$string = 'los mamíferos corren libres y quieren acompanar a su madre';

$forbidden = ['mamiferos', 'acompañar'];

function strip (string $accented): string {
    $decomposed = Normalizer::normalize ($accented, Normalizer::FORM_D);
    return preg_replace ('/\p{M}/u', '', $decomposed);
}

function filter (string $string, array $words): bool {
    $regex = '/\b(?:' . implode ('|', $words) . ')/i';
    return preg_match (strip ($regex), strip ($string));
}
echo ((filter ($string, $forbidden) ? 'match!' : 'nope...') . "\n");
```

By the way, I don't understand the meaning of `{3,}` in your regular expression, and I removed it from mine. If you think that it will match a string with three or more forbidden words, you are mistaken: the forbidden words will match only if they immediately follow each other.

Further reading: https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.normalizer.

Comment: Hi! Your solution looks like the right one. But i wanted to keep the `{3,}` part in the regex. Correct me if i'm wrong, but I added it so that the preg_match only tests the `$string` words that are 3 or more characters long. In my example, it would ignore the words "y", "a", "su".

Comment: @Andres SK, no, you are wrong. `{3,}` means "three or more repeats", in your case, of the preceding parentheses; that is, three or more forbidden words one after the other, without even a space between them. If you don't want to check `$string` that is two or less characters long, simply add `strlen` or `mb_strlen` to your `if`.

Comment: You can do much better with intl using the transliterator (and its infinite number of possibilities): https://3v4l.org/WI4rfH

Answer (score 1):

This works for me, all you want to do is to remove accent char from your input string, although not the best answer.

```
    $forbidden = array('mamiferos', 'acompañar');

    $string = 'los mamíferos corren libres y quieren acompanar a su madre';

    $stripted_accent = remove_accent($string);

    if(preg_match('/(' . remove_accent(implode('|', $forbidden)) .')/', $stripted_accent)) {

        echo 'match!';

    } else {

        echo 'nope...';

    }

    function remove_accent($accent) {
        return strtr(utf8_decode($accent), utf8_decode('àáâãäçèéêëìíîïñòóôõöùúûüýÿÀÁÂÃÄÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÑÒÓÔÕÖÙÚÛÜÝ'), 'aaaaaceeeeiiiinooooouuuuyyAAAAACEEEEIIIINOOOOOUUUUY');
    }
```